# Getting Schengen Visa with a French resident as sponsor

Tags: visas, schengen

I would apply for a 3 week tourist visa to France. I would be sponsored by a French resident who is my boyfriend. Do I still need to submit my ITR, bank certification and statements even though he will provide his original “attestation d’accueil”?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What citizenship do you hold?

Comment: From what I gather *attestation d'accueil* only has to do with room & board.  Financial support is entirely different.

Comment: As far as I know, you still need to provide all that but you [don't need as much money](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/doc_centre/borders/docs/notifications/Meansofsubsistencetable.pdf) to establish that you have “sufficient means of subsistence”.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to find clear guidance on this. What I could find so far:

- Means of subsistence and accommodation are clearly two separate requirements, you need to be able to prove you have both.
- If you have accommodation, you don't need as much money. According to [this table](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/doc_centre/borders/docs/notifications/Meansofsubsistencetable.pdf) (based on submission by each member state), in France, you need EUR 32.50 per day instead of EUR 65 if you didn't have accommodation.
- It's possible for your sponsor to cover all the costs of your stay. This is explicitly mentioned in the [*Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas*](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) and you can specify that in box 35 of [the standard visa application form](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/IMG/pdf/10._Formulaire_visa_court_sejour_document_no10_.pdf) but the [document found](http://www.ambafrance-my.org/IMG/pdf/SGSchengen_visa-3.pdf) by Jonathan Reez suggests that your sponsor should then provide his financial details.
- Your boyfriend should already [have submitted](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/particuliers/F2191.xhtml) some documents about his financial situation to get the *attestation d'accueil*. I don't know if that makes a difference.

In any case, the more details you submit, the more likely you are to receive a visa without delay even if there is some latitude in the evaluation of the requirement. So if possible at all, it would be best to submit your bank statements or tax fillings. If your financials look really bad and you had rather avoid disclosing that then make sure you have a letter from your boyfriend and as much documentation on his situation as possible.